# Local notification (UIUserNotificationActionContext.Minimal) does not show actions in simulator after first launch

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, ios8, ios9

I have local notifications, and I have two kinds of actions to perform, which I want to be displayed when the user gets notified.

Relevant code:

**AppDelegate:**

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool
{
    ......

    //local notifications part
    let completeAction = UIMutableUserNotificationAction()
    completeAction.identifier = "COMPLETE" // the unique identifier for this action
    completeAction.title = "Complete" // title for the action button
    completeAction.activationMode = .Background // UIUserNotificationActivationMode.Background - don't bring app to foreground
    completeAction.authenticationRequired = false // don't require unlocking before performing action
    completeAction.destructive = true // display action in red

    let callInAction = UIMutableUserNotificationAction()
    callInAction.identifier = "CALLIN"
    callInAction.title = "Call in"
    callInAction.activationMode = .Background
    callInAction.destructive = false

    let notificationCategory = UIMutableUserNotificationCategory() // notification categories allow us to create groups of actions that we can associate with a notification
    notificationCategory.identifier = "CALLINNOTIFICATION"
    notificationCategory.setActions([callInAction, completeAction], forContext: .Default) //UIUserNotificationActionContext.Default (4 actions max)
    notificationCategory.setActions([callInAction, completeAction], forContext: .Minimal) //UIUserNotificationActionContext.Minimal - for when space is limited (2 actions max)

    application.registerUserNotificationSettings(UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: [.Alert, .Badge, .Sound], categories: Set<UIUserNotificationCategory>.init(arrayLiteral: notificationCategory))) // we're now providing a set containing our category as an argument

    return true
}

func application(application: UIApplication, handleActionWithIdentifier identifier: String?, forLocalNotification notification: UILocalNotification, completionHandler: () -> Void) {
    //var item = TodoItem(deadline: notification.fireDate!, title: notification.userInfo!["title"] as String, UUID: notification.userInfo!["UUID"] as String!)
    switch (identifier!) {
    case "COMPLETE":
        print("complete")
       //do nothing for now
    case "CALLIN":
        print("gonnacall")
        let call = Call()
        call.withDevicePhone(method: Call.AS.UNDEFINED)

    default: // switch statements must be exhaustive - this condition should never be met
        print("Error: unexpected notification action identifier: \(identifier)")
    }
    completionHandler() // per developer documentation, app will terminate if we fail to call this
}
```

**Schedule notifications method:**

```
func scheduleLocalNotifications() {
....
if(event.startTime.timeIntervalSinceDate(NSDate()) > 0 && limitCounter <= 64){

                    let notification = UILocalNotification()
                    let minutesBefore = CallIn.Settings.notifyNumberOfMinutesBeforeEvent
                    notification.fireDate = event.startTime.dateByAddingTimeInterval(-minutesBefore * 60) //time of launch of notification

                    if(minutesBefore <= 1){
                        notification.alertBody = "Your \(event.title) is about to start"
                    }else{
                        notification.alertBody = "You have \(event.title) in \(Int(minutesBefore)) minutes"
                    }
                    notification.alertAction = "OK"
                    notification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName
                    notification.userInfo = ["title": event.title, "UUID": event.UUID, "CallIn": "CallInNotification"]
                    notification.category = "CALLINNOTIFICATION"
                    notification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 1

                    UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(notification)
                    limitCounter += 1
                }
.....
}
```

When I reset content and settings of the simulator, on the first launch I get two kinds of actions like supposed to:
[image]

However starting from the second launch, I never get the actions (not in the locked state, not in the notifications list, not as a popup alert style):
[image]

Comment: pls see my answer here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35036791/actions-buttons-not-showing-up-in-local-notifications-ios-9-2-swift-2